# Distributive monoidal categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Can anybody point me towards a paper where distributive monoidal categories are defined properly ? I have seen them mentioned in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+monoidal+category), but I wanted to check that nLab hasn't omitted any coherence conditions etc. I am also looking for a proof that each distributive monoidal category is a [rig category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig+category). If I could find literature about that it would be great, since it looks like one has to prove a lot of conditions to show that something is a rig category directly.

Comment: In the nLab article you link, you can go to the bottom and find the reference *Multitensors and monads on categories of enriched graphs* by Mark Weber. There is even a link (says tac:28-26) where you can download the paper. This one, in turn, has at least two references which include "distributive category" in the title. Does that work for you?

Comment: For the case of *symmetric* monoidal categories, the coherence conditions were obtained by Laplaza [Coherence for distributivity. In S. MacLane (Ed.), Coherence in Categories (pp. 29–65). Springer volume 281 of Lecture Notes in Mathematics.] For the *braided* case, Yuri Gurevich and I presented coherence conditions motivated by quantum applications, not pure math, in Braided distributivity [Theoret. Comp. Sci. 807 (2020) 73--94] (also available from Yuri's web site).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I have a couple of questions.  (1) Am I right in thinking that the categories Laplaza discusses are precisely the rig categories I linked to above ? (2) Are your BD categories generalizations of Laplaza's categories ?  Neither of these seem to be forced to be distributive categories in the sense of the nLab site I linked (which must involve coproducts), but I'm guessing such distributive categories (involving coproducts) are BD categories.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant to say "Are your BD categories SPECIAL CASES of Laplaza's categories ? "...